# Can 差す be an intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, verbs, transitivity

[WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) lists 差す as an intransitive verb, but in all of the example sentences I've seen it looks more like a transitive verb.

So my question is, is 差す a transitive or intransitive verb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's both. My copy of Kōjien has entries for both the transitive and intransitive uses of this verb.

**Intransitive**

- 夕日が部屋に差し込む。 (ゆうひがへやにさしこむ。)
- 潮が差す。 (しおがさす。)

**Transitive**

- 傘を差す。 (かさをさす。)
- 会話に水を差す。 (かいわにみずをさす。)

Comment: btw what does this means: 会話に水を差す

Comment: @Pacerier: 水を差す is an idiom roughly equivalent to the English phrase "be a wet blanket". ALC has [several other translations](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%B0%B4%E3%82%92%E5%B7%AE%E3%81%99/UTF-8/) for it.

Comment: ok cool thx for the help

Comment: @DerekSchaab I read in most dictionary that the meaning of 差し込む is to insert, to plug. As most dictionary may be course in the word-to-word translation, what english verb would you use in the 夕日が部屋に差し込む (I will checkin? in place of insert to?)